# NPM error when resolving modules (building Liferay Angular portlet)

Tags: angular, npm, liferay

I am getting an error “EMFILE: too many open files, open ‘(…)’ ”. I suspect it’s caused by the resolve NPM module (invoked by liferay-npm-bundler) having issues handling 1155 modules in my node_modules directory, running into the O/S (Windows) limit of number of open files.
I would be grateful for answers to several questions I have:

a)  Is there any way to increase the limit of open files in Windows?

b)  If not, is there a way to “trim” the number of modules in node_modules, eg. by removing modules installed by npm install but not really referenced/used by the application?

c)  Is there any other workaround for this problem/error?

Below are the details of the message I am getting.

```
Project assets copied.
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\liferay\LiferayWorkspacewithDevStudio7.4\liferay-workspace\modules\my-npm-angular-portlet2\node_modules\babel-preset-liferay-standard\package.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at defaultReadPackageSync (C:\liferay\LiferayWorkspacewithDevStudio7.4\liferay-workspace\modules\my-npm-angular-portlet2\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:58:16)
    at loadpkg (C:\liferay\LiferayWorkspacewithDevStudio7.4\liferay-workspace\modules\my-npm-angular-portlet2\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:151:19)
    at loadAsFileSync (C:\liferay\LiferayWorkspacewithDevStudio7.4\liferay-workspace\modules\my-npm-angular-portlet2\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:116:19)
    at loadAsDirectorySync (C:\liferay\LiferayWorkspacewithDevStudio7.4\liferay-workspace\modules\my-npm-angular-portlet2\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:191:16)
    at loadNodeModulesSync (C:\liferay\LiferayWorkspacewithDevStudio7.4\liferay-workspace\modules\my-npm-angular-portlet2\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:203:25)
    at Function.resolveSync [as sync] (C:\liferay\LiferayWorkspacewithDevStudio7.4\liferay-workspace\modules\my-npm-angular-portlet2\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:107:17)
    at Project.resolve (C:\liferay\LiferayWorkspacewithDevStudio7.4\liferay-workspace\modules\my-npm-angular-portlet2\node_modules\liferay-npm-build-tools-common\lib\project\index.js:228:34)
    at Project.toolResolve (C:\liferay\LiferayWorkspacewithDevStudio7.4\liferay-workspace\modules\my-npm-angular-portlet2\node_modules\liferay-npm-build-tools-common\lib\project\index.js:282:25)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-npm-angular-portlet2@1.0.0 build: `tsc && npm run copy-assets && liferay-npm-bundler`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I've seen it reported several times with no followups.